# Visual Studio 2017 community Watch window

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Currently I'm using the Community version of Visual Studio 2017 and having trouble finding the Watch Window using the debug menu or any other keyboard short cut methods. Does the watch window exist in VS2017 community? Or should use some other method for inspecting variable contents during debugging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please look in Debug - Windows - Watch menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was only able to get this to work by adding a break point during debugging. (The tutorial I was following did not have that step). I am able to see the watch window options (1 to 4) and advanced debugging tools now.

Comment: @RichardTeesdale same for me, could only get it to show up by using your breakpoint trick. Crazy that.

Answer (score 6):

You must first Debug your code with press<kbd>F5</kbd> key and then Watch window is added to Debug Menu and watch window as i said accessible from Debug>Window menu